# Jobadder API limit only showing 100 records - how to increase

Tags: php, curl

I have API connected with Jobadder using PHP, it only fetches 100 records. Jobadder has mentioned in thier docs that we can increase limit to 1000 or more but no sample code available: https://developers.jobadder.com/docs/#operation/FindJobBoardJobAds. Please help how to increase the limit here is the code:

````
curl_setopt_array($auth_curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://id.jobadder.com/connect/token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    'Content-type: x-www-form-urlencoded'
  ),
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($auth_data)
));

$auth_response = curl_exec($auth_curl);
curl_close($auth_curl);

$auth_val = json_decode($auth_response, true);
$new_token = $auth_val['access_token'];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://au3api.jobadder.com/v2/jobs/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,  
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer ". $new_token,
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$result = json_decode($response, true); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the limit on the end of your query string: `https://au3api.jobadder.com/v2/jobs/?limit=1000`.

This tells the back end to include 1000 results.  If you need to get more, add the offset to the URL: `https://au3api.jobadder.com/v2/jobs/?offset=1000&limit=1000`

I am assuming the offset is zero-based here.